# How to add RBAC roles to a Controller for a different kind of resource in Kubebuilder

Tags: kubernetes, rbac, kubernetes-operator, kubebuilder, kubernetes-rbac

I am creating a new Operator with Kubebuilder to deploy a Kubernetes controller to manage a new CRD Custom Resource Definition.

This new CRD (let's say is called `MyNewResource`), needs to list/create/delete CronJobs.

So in the Controller Go code where the `Reconcile(...)` method is defined I added a new RBAC comment to allow the reconciliation to work on CronJobs (see [here](https://book.kubebuilder.io/reference/markers/rbac.html)):

```golang
//+kubebuilder:rbac:groups=batch,resources=cronjobs,verbs=get;list;watch;create;update;patch;delete
```

However after building pushing and deploying the Docker/Kubernetes controller (repo `myrepo`, `make manifests`, then `make install`, then `make docker-build docker-push`, then `make deploy`), then in the logs I still see:

```
E0111 09:35:18.785523       1 reflector.go:138] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.22.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:167: Failed to watch *v1beta1.CronJob: failed to list *v1beta1.CronJob: cronjobs.batch is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:myrepo-system:myrepo-controller-manager" cannot list resource "cronjobs" in API group "batch" at the cluster scope
```

I also see issues about the cache, but they might not be related (not sure):

```
2022-01-11T09:35:57.857Z        ERROR   controller.mynewresource        Could not wait for Cache to sync        {"reconciler group": "mygroup.mydomain.com", "reconciler kind": "MyNewResource", "error": "failed to wait for mynewresource caches to sync: timed out waiting for cache to be synced"}
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/controller.(*Controller).Start
        /go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.10.0/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:234
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/manager.(*controllerManager).startRunnable.func1
        /go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.10.0/pkg/manager/internal.go:696
2022-01-11T09:35:57.858Z        ERROR   error received after stop sequence was engaged  {"error": "leader election lost"}
2022-01-11T09:35:57.858Z        ERROR   setup   problem running manager {"error": "failed to wait for mynewresource caches to sync: timed out waiting for cache to be synced"}
```

How can I allow my new Operator to deal with CronJobs resources?

At the moment basically I am not able to create new CronJobs programmatically (Go code) when I provide some YAML for a new instance of my CRD, by invoking:

```
kubectl create -f mynewresource-project/config/samples/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create new Role or ClusterRole (depending if you want your permissions to be namespaced or cluster-wide) and bind that to your `system:serviceaccount:myrepo-system:myrepo-controller-manager` user using RoleBinding/ClusterRoleBinding. I will provide examples for cluster-wide configuration.

ClusterRole:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: cronjobs-role
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["cronjobs"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list", "create", "update", "patch", "delete"]
```

Then, bind that using ClusterRoleBinding:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: cronjobs-rolebinding
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: system:serviceaccount:myrepo-system:myrepo-controller-manager
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cronjob-role
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Judging from your logs you might want to use `batch` apiGroup but I'll leave more generic example. More about k8s RBAC [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/).

**Kubebuilder**

With Kubebuilder the ClusterRole and the ClusterRoleBinding YAML code is autogenerated and stored in the `config/rbac/` directory.

To grant the binding on all groups (rather than just `batch`), you can place the Go comment with an asterisk like this:

```golang
//+kubebuilder:rbac:groups=*,resources=cronjobs,verbs=get;list;watch;create;update;patch;delete
```

This will change the autogenerated YAML for the `ClusterRole` to:

```
rules:
 - apiGroups:
   - '*' # instead of simply: batch
```

When deploying the updated operator, then the controller should be able to list/create/delete CronJobs.

See here for a [reference RBAC for Kubebuilder comments](https://book.kubebuilder.io/reference/markers/rbac.html)

Comment: This is great context - Kubebuilder is supposed to scaffold the source code based on the standard K8S API, but the documentation of both projects is a bit dry. Also: coming up with minimum viable examples is complex due to all the moving parts. Hopefully these code snippets will help when dealing with RBAC and the reconciler.